# Simple keyframe question in Blender animation

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have a simple object (let's assume it is a cube), which can be rigged by a bone. I inserted 3 LocRotScale keyframes at t1 = 0s, t2 = 5s and t3= 10s, let's call them *KF1*, *KF2* and *KF3*.

Between *KF1* and *KF2*, I only move (pressing key G) the cube.
Between *KF2* and *KF3*, I only rotate (pressing key R) the bone in the cube. 
With this setup, I expect the cube should start rotating only at time t2.
Strangely, when I play the animation, the bone/cube rotation ALREADY starts from time 0. What is wrong?

Comment: I think you should just add Location or LocScale keyframe for KF1 and KF2.

Comment: not sure about what you've done, have you moved the cube or the bone between K1 and K2? If you moved the cube, it's normal that the bone begin it's rotation between K1 and K3 as it's a different animation than the cube. If you moved the bone, make sure that you've inserted a LocRotScale keyframe at K2 and not only a Loc.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I just tried your suggestion, it didn't change the result...

Comment: Have you tried automatic keyframe method?

Comment: why did you move the cube? what you need to do is control your cube with the bone only. What you did is mixing the movement of one child object with the movement of one parent object, and they did what you asked, independently

Comment: Now I understand one thing: The keyframes are linked to objects! I didn't realise that before. Thank you so much! It works well now!

Comment: in the Dopesheet bottom menu, click on the arrow button, it allows to display only the keyframes of the selected object, it will help

Comment: Only rotation and scaling works in my parent relation. When I move the bone, the cube doesn't move... Are they not linked?

Comment: If the cube doesn't move when you move the bone, then it must not be rigged. Watch some rigging tutorials on youtube and you will know. By the way if you have something as simple as a cube then I don't think it needs bones. You can move and keyframe it directly....

Comment: I was too stupid to realise, I could simple select the bone and the cube using the shift key, and then G. They now move together. Thank you so much!

Comment: you must have parented as an Object and not as a Bone, so select the cube, then the Bone, and ctrl P > Set Parent to > Bone

Comment: you can choose to parent the cube to the bone to learn how the rigging works, in that case don't move the cube, only move the bone, it's now your controller

Comment: Yes, if it is only a cube, rigging is not necessary. In fact instead of the cube, I need to rig a human head.  Thank you both, I learned a lot today!

Comment: yes I will give it a try!

Comment: You should read about [keying sets](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/keyframes/keying_sets.html?highlight=keying%20set). Keying sets will allow you to add keyframes to specific properties.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake was to animate the cube while you should have only used the bone. There were two different animations: the cube and the bone. If you choose to parent your cube to a bone (with ctrl P > Set Parent to > Bone), then use the bone only to control the cube. By the way, in the Dopesheet bottom menu, click on the arrow button, it allows to display only the keyframes of the selected object, it will help.